# NestJS UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning by Promise

Tags: node.js, angular

when running my Get method in both Swagger and Postman, I get the following error message:

> (node:35014) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'error' of null
>       at HttpErrorFilter.catch (/Users/mapoferl/Documents/develop/BuergermeisterApp/backendnest/src/shared/http-error.filter.ts:28:31)
>       at ExceptionsHandler.invokeCustomFilters (/Users/mapoferl/Documents/develop/BuergermeisterApp/backendnest/node_modules/@nestjs/core/exceptions/exceptions-handler.js:31:26)
>       at ExceptionsHandler.next (/Users/mapoferl/Documents/develop/BuergermeisterApp/backendnest/node_modules/@nestjs/core/exceptions/exceptions-handler.js:12:18)
>       at /Users/mapoferl/Documents/develop/BuergermeisterApp/backendnest/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-proxy.js:12:35
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
>   (node:35014) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
>   (node:35014) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

d.service.ts

```
public async getCorporateDesignByDistrictName(name: string): Promise<CorporateDesign> {
    const district: District = await this.districtRepository.createQueryBuilder('district')
        .leftJoinAndSelect('district.mandant', 'mandant')
        .leftJoinAndSelect('district.corporateDesign', 'corporateDesign')
        .where('district.name = :name')
        .andWhere('district.isDeleted = :isDeleted')
        .setParameters({
            name: name,
            isDeleted: false
        })
        .getOne();
    return district.corporateDesign;
}
```

d.controller.ts

```
@UseGuards(AuthGuard)
@Get(':name')
public async getCorporateDesignByDistrictName(@Param('name') name: string): Promise<CorporateDesign> {
    return this.districtService.getCorporateDesignByDistrictName(name);
}
```

I'm using angular 8 and nest.js

Comment: What is `return district.corporateDesign;`?  Sounds like it's expected to be a promise

Comment: It is a variable of District. If i remove the Promise, async and await, the following error appears and I don't know how to fix it: _The return type of an async function or method must be the global Promise<T> type.ts(1064)_

Comment: show us your `http-error.filter.ts` file please. L28